# RoleEntryPoint trace calls are not being logged using the 2.0 Azure SDK for Cloud Services

Tags: azure, diagnostics

Scottgu just announced the 2.0 SDK:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/04/30/announcing-the-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-0-for-net.aspx

I tried creating a new MVC4 site. Added it to a cloud project and the following diagnostic setup was included as expected.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

According to : 
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/
the Windows Azure logs are on at default and

> Logs trace messages sent from your code to the trace listener (a trace
>   listener must be added to the web.config or app.config file). Log data
>   will be transferred at thescheduledTransferPeriodtransfer interval to
>   storage tableWADLogsTable.

the diagnostic.wadcfg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration configurationChangePollInterval="PT1M" overallQuotaInMB="4096" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
  <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs />
  <Directories>
    <IISLogs container="wad-iis-logfiles" />
    <CrashDumps container="wad-crash-dumps" />
  </Directories>
  <Logs bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" />
  <WindowsEventLog bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error">
    <DataSource name="Application!*" />
  </WindowsEventLog>
</DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
```

I placed a Trace.TraceError in both my global.cs and webrole.cs start methods and I do only get the one from global.cs.

Am i missing something or should it not also work for the WebRole?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WebRole.cs` is running in a different process than your application itself and your `web.config` does not affect it.

Try setting the `Trace Listeners` manually in code:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());
```

or use a solution from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx):

> **Reading config files from RoleEntryPoint and your web site:**
>   Even though the preferred way of storing configuration in Windows Azure
>   applications is in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file, there are
>   still many cases when you may want to use a normal .NET config file -
>   especially when configuring .NET system components or reusable
>   frameworks. In particular whenever you use Windows Azure diagnostics
>   you need to configure the DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener in a .NET
>   config file.
>
> When you create your web role project, Visual Studio creates a
>   web.config file for your .NET configuration. While your web
>   application can access this information, your RoleEntryPoint code
>   cannot-because it's not running as a part of your web site. As
>   mentioned earlier, it runs under a process called WaIISHost.exe, so it
>   expects its configuration to be in a file called WaIISHost.exe.config.
>   Therefore, if you create a file with this name in the your web project
>   and set the "Copy to Output Directory" property to "Copy Always"
>   you'll find that the RoleEntryPoint can read this happily. This is one
>   of the only cases I can think of where you'll have two .NET
>   configuration files in the same project!

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped that it was included in some way with this update from SDK2.0. Adding the listener myself works as you shown here. But i cant see the information inside visual studio in the new "View Diagnostic Data" entry in the server explorer. It filters the log to show only the stuff coming from the application and not the webrole. (I can find the entry in the table storage, but need a 3party tool to view it in a friendly manner).

Comment: Nvm, it seems to work in visual studio also for viewing the trace from the webrole.

Comment: This upvote is actually one million upvotes. Trace.Listeners.Add() does the job. This is the simplest explanation of what's going on after a day of bashing my head against the wall on this problem; thank you!